# What is the purpose of abstract signatures with no fields in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

I frequently see modelers using abstract signatures with no fields in their models. The abstract signatures usually have subsignature extensions but no fields. For instance, consider the following model from Jackson's book on Alloy:

```
abstract sig A {}
sig A1 extends A {}
sig A2 extends A {}
```

With no fields, how is A used after declaration? What is the point of making A abstract and how would the model be constrained differently if A was not abstract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the greatest value for an abstract sig comes when it has a field. And because Alloy has unions, you can write `A1+A2` instead of `A`. But even if it doesn't, there are advantages: by declaring `A` as an `abstract` sig, I can make my model easier to change. If I added a new sig `A3`, I would have to replace `A1 + A2` by `A1 + A2 + A3`, but with an abstract sig, it's still `A`. It also gives me a place to add a field later, and it makes specs shorter. And it allows me to give a scope to it; if I only had `A1` and `A2`, I would have to set their scopes separately, but setting a scope of `A` to 5 (say) allows the analyzer to allocate the atoms in any ratio between `A1` and `A2`. And in visualization, I can apply settings to A explicitly.